# Java if statement terminates without running

Tags: java, if-statement, java.util.scanner

I am making a basic calculator purely for study purposes. 
Here is the block of code in question:

```
Scanner Operation = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner data = new Scanner(System.in);
String add, sub, mul, div;
double fnum, snum, answer;

add = Operation.nextLine();
System.out.println(add);

if (Operation.equals("add")) {
    System.out.println("Enter the first number: ");
    fnum = data.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
    snum = data.nextDouble();
    answer = fnum + snum;
    System.out.println("Your answer is " + answer);
}
```

The program asks for two inputs and terminates without running the if statement.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Use better variable names and the mistake will be self-evident.

Comment: Why are you using two Scanner instances ?

Comment: @Rishabh Maurya. Thank you for pointing that out. I just fixed that.

Comment: @shmosel Thank you too, Can you give me a better variable name as an example please. I am new to Java and I thought the variable names just need to be short and define the explanation of its content.

Comment: Does the name `Operation` sound like it holds a `Scanner` object? Does `add` sound like it can be the name of a variety of math operations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Operation` is your `Scanner`, `add` is the `String` you read into.

This

```
if (Operation.equals("add")) {
```

should be

```
if (add.equals("add")) {
```

But honestly, you should pick more meaningful variable names.

Comment: That fixed the issue, thank you very much. Now I am trying to add another operation into this program and the code is very similar with the addition code I have posted. The code can conclude the correct answer but I have to input my "operation" twice and it is giving me an error.

Comment: The error has been resolved but I still need to give it input multiple times.